# Different norms for the $H^{1/2}$ sobolev spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces, trace-map

**I am looking for references for the following results, which i believe to be true :**

Let $B$ a Lipschitz domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $f \in H^{1/2}(\partial B)$. We note $\gamma_0 : H^1(B) \mapsto H^{1/2}(\partial B)$ the natural trace application for $B$. I know we can provide $H^{1/2}(\partial B)$  with the following norm :

\begin{equation}
    ||f||_{H^{1/2}(\partial B)} = \underset{G \in H^1(B) \atop
     \gamma_0(G)|_{\partial B}=f}{\inf}||G||_{H^1(B)}.
\end{equation}
Let $A$ a bounded open set with regular boundaries such as $B \subset A$. We note $N : H^{1/2}(\partial B) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ defined by :

\begin{equation}
    N(f) = \underset{G \in H^1(A \setminus B) \atop
     \tilde{\gamma_0}(G)|_{\partial B}=f \text{ et } \tilde{\gamma_0}(G)|_{\partial A}=0}{\inf}||\nabla G||_{(L^2(A \setminus B))^{d^2}}.
\end{equation}
where $\tilde{\gamma_0} : H^1(A \setminus B) \mapsto H^{1/2}(\partial A \cup \partial B)$ is the natural trace application for the space $A \setminus B$.

**I am looking to prove that $N$ is a norm for $H^{1/2}(\partial B)$ and that $N$ and $||.||_{H^{1/2}(\partial B)}$ are equivalent norms.**

---

In concrete terms, this results means that it is the same to define a norm on $H^{1/2}(\partial B)$ weither you extend $f$ in the exterior ($A \setminus B)$ or interior ($B$) of $\partial B$.

I already looked in, among other sources :

*Galdi, Giovanni P.*, An introduction to the mathematical theory of the Navier-Stokes equations. Vol. I: Linearized steady problems, Springer Tracts in Natural Philosophy. 38. New York, NY: Springer-Verlag. xi, 450 p. (1994). [ZBL0949.35004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0949.35004).

*Evans, Lawrence C.*, Partial differential equations, Graduate Studies in Mathematics. 19. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xvii, 662 p. (1998). [ZBL0902.35002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0902.35002).

Any help or information are welcomed !

Comment: I guess you mean $\partial A  \,{\color{red}\cup}\, \partial B$.

Comment: what definitely should work if you define $$N(f) = \inf_{G \in H^1(B^{\mathsf{c}}), \gamma_0 G = f} \|G\|_{H^1(B^{\mathsf{c}})}$$

Comment: Thanks @NathanaelSkrepek. Indeed, if I note your norm $$\tilde{N}(f)= \underset{G \in H^1(B^c), \gamma_0 G =f}{\inf} ||G||_{H^1(B^c)}$$ I am able to show that my norm $N$ is equivalent to $\tilde{N}$. However, I don't know how to prove that $\tilde{N}$ and $||.||_{H^{1/2}(\partial B)}$ are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is maybe an alternative way : showing that for $g \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, the trace on $\partial B$ is the same for $g$ which is seen as an element of $H^1(B)$ or as an element of $H^1(B^c)$. If you denote those two elements $\gamma g$ and $\widetilde{\gamma} g$, you can play with infimum and the continuous extension operators (from $B$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $B^c$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$) to show that you have indeed
$$||\cdot||_{H^{1/2}(\partial B)} \sim \widetilde{N}$$
(with your previous notations).

The point is now to see that the traces above are the same. I think the main point is to understand why the trace actually only depends on $\partial B$ as a manifold and not on $B$ or $B^c$. I suggest you have a look to the following famous book :

F. Boyer, P. Fabrie : Mathematical tools for the study of the incompressible Navier-Stokes equations and related models, Applied Mathematical Sciences, vol. 183, Springer (2013)

and more precisely Section 2.5.1. (even if it relies on some previous notations inside the book...) I think that you can convince yourself that the construction of the trace yields the same map for a $g \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (the partition of unity you use is the same and you control all the norms on $B$ or $B^c$ by the same norms on $\mathbb{R}^d$).

Answer (score 2):

Given that $N$ and $\tilde{N}$ are equivalent as you mentioned in the comments, I think this proves your statement:
The norm
\begin{equation}
    \|f\|_{H^{1/2}(\partial B)} := \inf_{G \in H^1(B),\gamma_0(G)=f}\|G\|_{H^1(B)}.
\end{equation}
is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{\ast} := \left(\|f\|^2_{L^2(\partial B)} + \int_{\partial B} \int_{\partial B} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^2}{\|x-y\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}^n} 
\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align*}
which is in turn equivalent to
\begin{align*}
  \|f\|_{H^{1/2}(\partial (B^{\mathsf{c}}))}
  := \inf_{G \in H^1(B^c),\gamma_0(G)=f}\|G\|_{H^1(B^{\mathsf{c}})}.
\end{align*}
which is $\tilde{N}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Am I allowed to use $||.||_*$ as a norm on $H^{1/2}(\partial B)$ ? I am aware that $$||u||^2_s=||u||^2_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}+ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^2}{||x-y||^{2(s+\frac{d}{2})}_{\mathbb{R}^d}} \ dx dy$$ defines a norm on the fractional sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$  for $s \in ]0,1[$, but the demonstration I know uses the Fourier transform norm : $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\hat{u}(\xi)|^2(1+|\xi|^2)^s \ d\xi$$ but i'm not sure I can rely on the norm $||.||_*$ since Fourier transform should no more be possible ($\partial B$ is bounded).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure but I think it should be better to use $$||f||_*=\left( ||f||_{L^2(\partial B)} + \int_{\partial B} \int_{\partial B} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^2}{||x-y||^d_{\mathbb{R}^d}} \ dx dy \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$. I actually found something that proves that $||.||_{*}$ is indeed a norm for $H^{1/2}(\partial B)$, but I don't know how to prove that it is equivalent to my norms $||.||_{H^{1/2}(\partial B)}$ and $||.||_{H^{1/2}(\partial B^c)}$.

Comment: @Velobos I have seen it a lot that this norm is equivalent to the $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$ that is given by the range norm of $H^1(\Omega)$, but I also don't know where you can find a reference for this.
However, probably you will find references in https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4345v3
I edited the norm in my post according to your suggestion